# Is it possible to use .self for components that were not created dynamically?

Tags: delphi, self

If I have 20 panels on a form (not dynamic) and want to change the color of them when the mouse hovers over them, can I use `self.color`? I have tried this but it changes the forms color. Somebody suggested that I try assigning each panel to itself by using `panel1.assign(panel1)`, although there was an error that said a TPanel cannot be assigned to itself. I've also tried `Form1.free`, but that also didn't help.

Do I have to create the panels dynamically to use Self or is there another way?

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you think [`Self`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Self) can somehow know that you want to reference the panels? `Self` *always* references the current class context of the code. I also don't know why you think dynamically creating them would allow you to use `Self`. That's even less applicable. I cannot see any relevance between use of `Self` and creating panels on a form.

Comment: I thought `Self` referred to the component that the code was in, I was changing their color in the OnMouseEnter events of the panels. Is there a way of referencing a component based on which components event the code is written in?

Comment: `Self` refers to the current instance. I'd guess that in your case it will refer to a form. Not what you want. This is unfortunately an XY question. You asked about `Self`, but nothing that we can tell you about `Self` helps you because it is not the solution to the real problem. Ask about the real problem. Don't ask about your non-working solution.

Comment: @JerryDodge `Self always references the current class context of the code` - until I assign something else to `Self` - it is not read-only ;-)

Comment: @mjn42 That's exactly why I worded it that way using the word "context". I've actually seen someone use `with [something] do ... Self.DoSomething ...` and wonder why it didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
type
  TPanel = class(Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPanel)
  protected
    procedure MouseEnter; override;
    procedure MouseLeave; override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TPanel.MouseEnter;
begin
  inherited;
  Color := clBlack;
end;

procedure TPanel.MouseLeave;
begin
  inherited;
  Color := clBtnFace;
end;
```

Comment: Or use the `Sender` parameter to the corresponding `OnXXX` events

Comment: @Jerry, true. I'd delete this post in favor of the other answer but it's locked.

Comment: This answer is basically  fine but an interposer presents the problem Jerry mentions. Rename the class and that problem is gone.

Comment: @David, but then it won't be interposer class. You would need to modify the class names of the desired components inside the form declaration and that would fail to correspond with the .dfm.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are assigning `OnMouse(Enter|Leave)` event handlers at design-time, the handlers will belong to your `TForm` class, that is why the `Self` pointer refers to the Form object at runtime.  Use the handler's `Sender` parameter instead, that points to the object that is actually triggering the event, eg:

```
procedure TMyForm.Panel1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TPanel(Sender).Color := ...;
end;

procedure TMyForm.Panel1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TPanel(Sender).Color := ...;
end;
```